# General methods to deal with time series data

Tags: time-series

Sorry I'm new to machine learning and statistics.

For time series predictions, do you use RNN or something? For example, the past 2 years' sales of a product.

TBH Im pretty much unfamiliar with how statisticians deal with time series data.

I'm dealing with some time series problems and I'm not sure if I should put all my trust on RNN or some other DL models.

Sorry I'm unable to provide the specific data here, don't know if it will cause vagueness. But the sales data is definitely a topic of interest.

Comment: There are entire textbooks dedicated to time series analysis that will not even address modern methods that involve neural networks. Do you have a more focused question on time series analysis?

Comment: @Dave Thank you! I can't provide too specific data as it relates to my thesis, but you can view it as the sales data as I mentioned. BTW what do you think of the RNN models? do you trust it? I mean if it works fine then I dont have to research on other models

Comment: RNNs are actually not very often seen in academic forecasting competitions. The dominant contender for the M5 competition was LightGBM in various flavors and combination with predictors. What kind of sales are you looking at? Retail sales behave very differently from electricity demands per household, or total car sales per year.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Stock price data tbh but there seems to be a lot of non deep learning methods for it. I just dont have enough time to read them.
BTW where is the M5 competition held? is it on Kaggle? Would you like to provide me the link?

Comment: Stock prices are yet something completely different, I wouldn't call these "sales". In that case, the M6 competition is probably more appropriate: https://m6competition.com/. It's not on Kaggle, probably because Kaggle does not support rolling origins. But there should be forums on the M6 website somewhere.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you! it seems I cannot download the models from the leaderboard? maybe because the competition is still ongoing? Would you please tell me where you got the models of the M5 competition?

Comment: Probably, yes. The M5 competition was hosted at Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/m5-forecasting-accuracy. There was an entire [special issue of the *IJF*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/international-journal-of-forecasting/vol/38/issue/4) devoted to it. But it was on retail sales from Walmart, so the applicability to stock prices is dubious.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you! Im very interested in the retail sales data as well. TBH it (sales data) has something to do with one of my past interviews for a data scientist internship.

Comment: If you are also interested in retail forecasting, there is an entire review paper on that in the M5 *IJF* special issue, by Fildes, Ma & Kolassa, plus a postscript. And if you search for my name and "retail forecasting" on YouTube, you will find a few videos you might find interesting.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you! I have found your videos on youtube. Very educational I'm very glad I found your opinions on deep learning models in the video.